night light not working on ubuntu 24.04 LTS
my night light worked on 22.04 but after the 24.04 update its not working.
my graphic is uptodate and i use HP ProDesk.
none of the option in the night light menu changes any thing

Have you checked under Settings » Displays » Night Light if it is enable and if the schedule is right (e.g. sunset-sunrise, or a fixed time).
I have noticed the toggle in the main menu does not toggle night light itself, it merely toggles the setting, so it seems.

What worked for me is under Settings>Displays>Schedule>Manual Schedule, to set a time corresponding to my sunrise and sunset. And then set schedule back to [Sunset to Sunrise].
